# How to pass array as arguments

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, gridview, plsql

I have 2 tables in 1 database

```
TABLE 1: LOGS
TABLE 2: MASTER LIST

LOGS
HOST | USER | NAME
==================
1    | A    | A1 
1    | A    | B1
1    | A    | C1
1    | A    | D1

MASTER LIST 
HOST | USER | NAME
===================
1    | A    | A1
1    | A    | B1
1    | A    | C1
```

On my C# program, I have a gridview, I need to highlight the row which is not included in the master list

```
LOGS
HOST | USER | NAME
==================
1    | A    | A1 
1    | A    | B1
1    | A    | C1
**1    | A    | D1**
```

Here is my C# Code:

```
           //Create the OracleCommand

            OracleCommand OCom = new OracleCommand("SERVERSTATUS.LOG_LIST", oc);

            OCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

           OCom.Parameters.Add("out_RESULT", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            OCom.Parameters[0].Value = sid;

            OracleDataAdapter _daGrid1 = new OracleDataAdapter(OCom);

            _daGrid1.Fill(_dsGrid);

            _daGrid1.Dispose();
            _daGrid1 = null;

            OCom.Dispose();
            OCom = null;

            if (frm_IT010_03 == null)
            {
                //button click show form with gridview
                frm_IT010_03 = new IT010_03(_dsGrid); 
                frm_IT010_03.ShowDialog();
            }
```

Class LogArray: This class store data from the database to the array.. How can I call the class? So I can compare it up with the grid..

```
 public void LogArray(ArrayList al)
    {

        OracleConnection oc = new OracleConnection(ConOra);
        DataSet _dsGrid = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            oc.Open();
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        try
        {
            OracleCommand OCom = new OracleCommand("SERVERSTATUS.LOG_STATUS", oc);
            OCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            OCom.Parameters.Add("out_RESULT", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            OracleDataReader DataReader = OCom.ExecuteReader();

            while (DataReader.Read())
            {
                al.Add(DataReader.GetString(0));
            }

        }
        catch
     {
    ...
     }
```

I have compiled a Package with 2 procedures in Oracle

```
Package name: Server Status
Procedure name: **Log_list** = Calls for the Logs Table
Procedure name: **Log_status** = Calls for the values that are in the logs table but is not included in the master list table.
```

Thanks!! =))

Comment: It looks to me like you'd use your LOG_LIST procedure to populate the grid, then call the LOG_STATUS routine to get the values which exist in LOGS but not in MASTER LIST, loop through your grid to find the entries which match what's returned by LOG_STATUS, and set the background and foreground of the cells in the corresponding row to be "highlighted".  Share and enjoy.

Comment: I edited my code and added a class with array.. so I can compare them with the grid.. How can I call the array? Or is my code alright?

Comment: If you just need to highlight the record then why not add another column which indicates if to highlight or not (i.e. with a VIEW) ? this could be simply done with sql...

Comment: Could you please show me a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand you, but if you only need to know which records to highlight, then you can have it in the sql (or plsql).

Your query can be something like this:

```
select l.HOST, l.USER, l.NAME, case when ml.HOST is null then 1 else 0 end is_to_highlight
from LOGS l left outer join MASTER_LIST ml on l.HOST = ml.HOST 
and l.USER= ml.USER 
and l.NAME = ml.NAME
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e991a/3)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. =) in my c# code, if is_to_highlight == 1 then highlight the row..is that what are you trying to mean?

Comment: Thanks for the sqlfiddle also.. =)

Comment: @QKWS, yes and if 0 then don't highlight